# multiple countdown with mysql

Tags: php, javascript

I have a serious problem and I can't resolve.
    I need to put multiple countdown to work but in my code, just one countdown works fine.
    I can't understand why the others datetime can't be read.
    I'm using database to get datetime.

Here my code:

```
$stmt4 = $mybd->prepare($query3);
$stmt4->bind_param("s",$cat);                               
$stmt4->execute();
$stmt4->bind_result($idVoucher,$titulo,$descricao, $precoOriginal, $desconto,$data, $nome, $nomeImagem);
while($stmt4->fetch()){
     if($cat == $nome){
    if($idVoucher != $idVoucher2){

     echo "<input id='data2' type='hidden'  value='$data' />";
```

And i using this script to countdown:

```
$(function(){

    var data = $('#data').val();
    var date_split = data.split(" ");
    var date = date_split[0];
    date = date.split("-");
    var time = date_split[1];
    time = time.split(":");

    var data1 = $('#data2').val();
    var date_split1 = data1.split(" ");
    var date1 = date_split1[0];
    date1 = date1.split("-");
    var time1 = date_split1[1];
    time1 = time1.split(":");

    var note = $('#note'),
        ts = new Date(date[0], date[1] - 01,date[2], time[0], time[1],time[2]),
        newYear = true;

    var note1 = $('#note1'),
        ts2 = new Date(date1[0], date1[1] - 01,date1[2], time1[0], time1[1],time1[2]),
        newYear = true;

    /*  if((new Date()) > ts){
        // The new year is here! Count towards something else.
        // Notice the *1000 at the end - time must be in milliseconds
        ts = (new Date()).getTime() + 10*24*60*60*1000;
        newYear = false;
    } */

    $('#endtime_1320').countdown({
        timestamp   : ts,
        callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){

            var message = "";

            message += days + " day" + ( days==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
            message += hours + " hour" + ( hours==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
            message += minutes + " minute" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'s' ) + " and ";
            message += seconds + " second" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'s' ) + " <br />";
        }
    });

    $('#endtime_1321').countdown({
        timestamp   : ts2,
        callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){

            var message = "";

            message += days + " day" + ( days==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
            message += hours + " hour" + ( hours==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
            message += minutes + " minute" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'s' ) + " and ";
            message += seconds + " second" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'s' ) + " <br />";
        }
    });
});
```

How I can resolve this?
keep my dateTimes into array and using into my script?
For the case, how i did that?

Thanks

Comment: What `countdown` plugin are you using? Could you create a jsFiddle showing your issue - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I'm using this tutorial...http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/

Comment: You are missing some key elements in the code you have posted - `<input id='data'>`, `<div id="endtime_1320">`, 
`<div id="endtime_1321">`, and the `$date` values you have in the hidden inputs. The issue is somewhere in there as I was able to create this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GMnMc/4/ - that uses your javascript code, and it works to have 2 countdowns.

Comment: your code is good but i have a problem...i have a while in my code and it always get the data in my database but the <div id="endtime_1321"> is the same for any new data. This causes trouble because he shows always the first data from my loop. I need to change the number of the endtime <div id="endtime_1321"> each time i have a new data from my DB.

Comment: my example was to show that your javascript is working. Can you show your full while loop, as well as the resulting html code. Your issue is somewhere in there, and I can't see it in the truncated example you posted.

Comment: I solved my problem but now i have another problem...I would like to update my information when the countdown finish. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem...There is the code if anyone wants to use.
I used the Keith-Wood countdown and my countdown works fine but now I want another question.
When the countdown finish, i want to update into my database.

How I discover when the countdown finish and next update into my database?

$query3 = "select v.id,v.titulo,v.descricao,v.precoOriginal,v.desconto,v.dataFinal,v.estado, c.nome,i.nome,i.tipo from voucher as v
                                  LEFT JOIN categoria as c on v.id_categoria = c.id
                                  LEFT JOIN imagem as i on i.id_Voucher = v.id
                                  WHERE c.nome = ?
                                  ORDER BY v.id DESC"; 
                        $stmt3 = $mybd->prepare($query3);
                        $stmt3->bind_param("s",$cat);
                        $stmt3->execute();
                        $stmt3->bind_result($idVoucher,$titulo,$descricao, $precoOriginal, $desconto,$data,$estado, $nome, $nomeImagem,$tipo);

```
                    while($stmt3->fetch()){
                        if($nome == $cat){
                            if($idVoucher == $idVoucher2 && $estado == "ativo" && $tipo == "paginaPrincipal"){ ?>
                                    <h2><a href='./verOfertaCompra.php' ><?php echo $titulo ?></a></h2>
                                    <img class='imagem' src='./images/paginaPrincipal/<?php echo $nomeImagem; ?>' />
                                    <div class='info'>
                                        <div class='primeiro'>
                                        <input class='data<?php echo $idVoucher ?>' type='hidden'  value=<?php echo $data; ?> /><br/>
                                        <span style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; margin-left:38px;">Este Voucher termina em </span><br/><br/>
                                        <div id="defaultCountdown" class="endtime<?php echo $idVoucher ?>"></div>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                                $(function () {
                                                        var i = <?php echo $idVoucher ?>;
                                                        var dataVal = $(".data" + i.toString()).val();
                                                        var data = new Date(dataVal);
                                                        str = ".endtime"+i.toString();
                                                        $(str).countdown({until: data, format: 'dHMS'});
                                                    });
                                            </script>
                                        <?php
```